# Problem with an exercise about maximal subgroups in nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory, nilpotence

I'm trying to resolve the following exercise.

Let be $G$ a nilpotent group, A a maximal abelian and normal subgroup in G. 
Then $C_G(A)=A$.

Now my question is: if I choose $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=p\mathbb{Z}$, they satisfy the hypothesis but I have that $C_G(A)=G$.

Where is my mistake? Is there a mistake in the text exercise, since this seems to be an easy counterexample?

Comment: $p\mathbb{Z}$ is not maximal abelian (when adding the "abelian" part, maximal no longer means maximal and proper).

Comment: If you took $G$ as abelian then you have  $A=G$. It is not reqired that $A$ is proper.

Comment: Should our group to be Non Abelian